# Can I record stereo on dynamic mics?

Tags: recording, stereo

Can I record stereo on dynamic mics? I heard that stereo sound needs some distance. But dynamic microphones are recording at a very close distance.

> You simply don’t have enough space for a stereo image to develop until you’re at least 6 feet from the instrument or group of instruments. In fact, you should be at least 10 feet from the sound source before using the X-Y stereo miking approach.

Comment: It will depend a lot on *what* you want to record, and *where* it will be recorded.

Comment: The link to your quote is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely can use dynamic mics for stereo, though it may not give quite as good results as with condensers. Dynamic mics have a somewhat more unpredictable phase response especially off-angle, which can make the spatial perception feel off. But simple XY-pattern (which relies mostly on amplitude anyway) works well, as does AB with widely spaced mics or close to the source (both of which causes the natural amplitude- and phase separation to dominate anything the microphone imperfections introduce).

Yes, dynamic mics are *usually* used at close distance. They are not as sensitive as condenser mics, so when picking up a quiet source at distance you need to crank the preamp gain, which raises the noise level. But for recording e.g. a brass band, this wouldn't be a problem, and with good preamps even a quieter ensemble would be ok.

On top of that, the general issues apply as well of course: dynamic mics have difficulties capturing quite as crisp treble frequencies as condensers. But again, whether this is a problem depends on what source you're picking up.